# Is it proper to write "Be watching"

Tags: word-usage

Examples:

Be watching for an email within 24 hours to begin ordering.

Please be watching for this Questionnaire coming your way in March or April.

Comment: This is a proper way to write.  It may be more common to say "watch" instead of "be watching."

Comment: @Karlomanio Not _may_ be more common but _definitely_ more common. No native speaker that I know of would say "be watching", it would always be "watch for", "watch out for" or "look out for". "Be watching" might be common somewhere but I don't know where: reading it would make me think that the writer was not a native speaker.

Comment: In American English we often say things like "Be looking out for X".  For example, *We will pick you up at the airport. Our rental car is a white Honda . **Be looking out for it**.*

Comment: @TRomano: Really? I never hear it in the progressive form, only as "Look out for ..." or "Be on the lookout for ..."

Comment: @Robusto: See https://www.facebook.com/114021631989210/photos/a.747178595340174/1983511858373502/?type=3&theater  *Be looking out for us as you go to class today!!*

Comment: @TRomano: I don't use Facebook. And I didn't say it wasn't possible, just that I never hear it.

Comment: @Robusto: I didn't say you said it was impossible. But now you've "heard" it.

Comment: @TRomano: I just told you I don't use Facebook.

Comment: Keep looking might be an alternative.

Comment: @Robusto: And I just told you that now you've "heard" it since I quoted the relevant phrase in my comment.  No need for you to visit Facebook.

Comment: I don't accept Facebook as a source of anything except mischief. Anyway, one swallow doesn't make a summer.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to convey the progressive meaning of 'watch', use other aspectual verbs than 'be' such as 'keep' or 'continue':

> **Keep watching** for an email within 24 hours to begin ordering.
>
> Please **keep watching** for this Questionnaire coming your way in March or April.

OR

> **Continue watching** for an email within 24 hours to begin ordering.
>
> Please **continue watching** for this Questionnaire coming your way in March or April.

OR

> **Continue to watch** for an email within 24 hours to begin ordering.
>
> Please **continue to watch** for this Questionnaire coming your way in March or April.

To my ears, these work far better than your examples with 'be'.